# Returning a value from a cypress command / request

Tags: typescript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I would like to return an access token from a cypress request, I am doing this in commands as it will be used frequently, the current code is using `cy.wrap` but this feels very cumbersome for something so simple.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getToken',
  (email: string, password: string) => {
    cy.request('POST', `/token`, {
      email,
      password,
    }).then(({ body }) => cy.wrap(body.access_token));
  }
);
```

When this is used I have to do the following:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'createCustomAudience',
  (queries: string[]) => {
    cy.getToken('email', 'password').then((token) => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/audiences/custom`,
        body: {
          queries,
        },
        auth: { bearer: token },
      })
        .then(({ body }) => cy.wrap(body))
        .then((body) => cy.log(body as unknown as string));
    });
  }
);
```

Just to log the body I have to call .then twice and wrap it again and then double coerce!

This code works but surely there is a nicer was to do this, more async/await style - or maybe there is a way to just use plain JS/TS to do this?

I am using `Cypress v10.6.0`.

Comment: So you want to use one custom command inside another custom command?

Comment: That is not the problem.

The problem is how to cleanly return a value from a request call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `cy.wrap()`, or a `return` in the Cypress command, or type casting.

You do need custom declarations for the commands, and it's easiest to put them in `cypress/support/index.d.ts`

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    getToken(email: string, password: string): Chainable<string>
    createCustomAudience(queries: string[]): Chainable<string>
  }
}
```

Make sure there's an entry in `tsconfig.json` include to find it:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.cy.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",   // this catches your custom index.d.ts
    ...
  ]
}
```

**Test**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getToken', (email, password) => {

  cy.request('POST', '/token', {      // command result is automatically returned 
    email,
    password,
  })
  .then(response => response.body.access_token)  // modifies the result 
})

Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomAudience', (queries) => {
  cy.getToken('email', 'password').then((token) => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `/audiences/custom`,
      body: {
        queries,
      },
      auth: { bearer: token },
    })
    .then(response => response.body)   // type is known from index.d.ts
  });
})
```

---

**With async/await token fetch**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomAudience', async (queries) => {

  const token = await fetch(Cypress.config('baseUrl') + '/token', {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: { email: 'my-email', password: 'my-password' }
  })

  cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `/audiences/custom`,
      body: {
        queries,
      },
      auth: { bearer: token },
  })
  .then(response => response.body)   // type is known from index.d.ts
})
```

It appears you've hard-coded the email/password in the original, but likely you would grab those from `Cypress.env()`.

Comment: Thanks this looks pretty neat! But is there no way to then use `getToken` in the following manner: `const token = cy.getToken('email', 'password');` ?

Comment: Yes, you can throw away the `cy.getToken()` custom command and use a plain Javascript fetch in it's place in `cy.createCustomAudience()` - to save one `.then()` call?

Comment: Thanks, would you mind adding that option to the answer and I will accept it?

Comment: I get an error when adding the "async" like in your last example saying that:


`Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CommandFn<"seedDB">'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Chainable<null>'.
    Type 'Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Chainable<null>': and, as, selectFile, blur, and 86 more.ts(2345)`
Do you have any suggestions about how to make a cypress command allow async?

Comment: The above works - Sorry I can't tell from that error message what is going wrong for you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to return the chain of Cypress commands that yields the value you want to use.

Also, you can use `.its()` to get the access_token.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getToken',
  (email: string, password: string) => {
    return cy.request('POST', `/token`, {
      email,
      password,
    }).its('body.access_token');
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks this also looks pretty neat! But is there no way to then use `getToken` in the following manner: `const token = cy.getToken('email', 'password');` ?